# How to optimize the sql query with aggregate function?

Tags: sql-server

Below is the sql query i want to optimize.

```
 SELECT (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM tblPayment WHERE TransactionType = 1 and AccountType = 2 and Status = 3),0) 
         +
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM tblPayment WHERE TransactionType = 2 and AccountType = 2 and Status = 3),0)
        ) 'Total Funds'
```

How can i optimize it in a better way ?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Erase after the `+` and change to read `WHERE TransactionType IN(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two different queries to `sum TransactionType = 1` and `TransactionType = 2` use `TransactionType in (1,2)`

```
SELECT Isnull(Sum(Amount),0)
FROM   tblPayment
WHERE  TransactionType IN( 1, 2 )
       AND AccountType = 2
       AND Status = 3
```

Comment: You could maybe wrap that in an IsNull to match the paranoia of the original request and ensure a numeric result, but otherwise good answer. +

Comment: Thanks NoDisplayName!

Comment: Right, but if they're *all* null or there are no records, won't it return a NULL?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount), 0) AS [Total Funds]
FROM tblPayment
WHERE AccountType = 2 AND Status = 3 
      AND TransactionType IN (1,2)
```